# Can not get url image storage firebase [ Error creating access token]

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage

[image]

I tried uploading the image to firebase and now I can't get the image URL

I uploaded the image successfully and can't get the image's URL link

```
   const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
// change the path of json file
const serviceAccount = require('./nodejs-be-upload-image-firebase-adminsdk-vzkga-bd1696a09f.json');

const admin = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});
const storageRef = admin.storage().bucket('gs://nodejs-be-upload-image.appspot.com');

async function uploadFile(path, filename) {
  // Upload the File
  const storage = await storageRef.upload(path, {
    public: true,
    destination: `/uploads/${filename}`,
    metadata: {
      firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuidv4(),
      cacheControl: 'public, max-age=315360000',
      contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    },
  });

 //I want to get the URL of the image here
    return storage[0];
//  return storage[0].metadata.mediaLink;
}
module.exports = { uploadFile };
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Admin SDK wraps the Google Cloud Storage SDK, so their APIs are the same. The Cloud Storage SDK doesn't offer download URLs that are exactly like the ones provided by the mobile and web SDKs.

By setting the image or file as public (`public: true`) you wont be able to set a custom `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` metadata.

---

There are some ways that you can get the public URL of an uploaded file.

Using [**`getSignedUrl`**](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/#getSignedUrl):

```
const admin = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert({
    // serviceAccount
  }),
});

const gs = 'gs://'
const bucketName = '<project-id>.appspot.com';
const storageRef = admin.storage().bucket(`${gs}${bucketName}`);

async function uploadFile(path, filename) {
  // Upload the File
  const destination = `uploads/${filename}`;

  const storage = await storageRef.upload(path, {
    public: true,
    destination: destination,
  })
  .then(() => {
    const file = storageRef.file(destination);
    return file.getSignedUrl({
      action: 'read',
      expires: '03-25-2023'
    }).then(signedUrls => {
      // signedUrls[0] contains the file's public URL
      console.log(signedUrls[0]);
    });
  });
}
```

Using the Cloud Storage link:

```
async function uploadFile(path, filename) {
  // Upload the File
  const destination = `uploads/${filename}`;

  const storage = await storageRef.upload(path, {
    public: true,
    destination: destination,
  })
  .then(() => {
  console.log(`https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucketName}/${destination}`);
  });
}
```

If you really do want to use customMetadata that has the `firebaseStorageDownloadTokens` then I would suggest to use the Web SDKs instead. Here's the documentation to start:

- [Get started with Cloud Storage on Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start).

Comment: I'm tried getSignedUrl but it not working. 
`<Error>
<script/>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message>
<StringToSign>GET 1679677200 /nodejs-be-upload-image.appspot.com/uploads/image-1648210854263-590274585-25b76e6471271c9358b6a895544bd20c.jpg</StringToSign>
</Error>`

Comment: Are you clicking the link from the console log or copy and pasting it on your browser?

Comment: yes, I clicking the link from the console log and it show above error

Comment: You shouldn't click it on the console log. Try to copy the link from the console log and paste in a browser. Clicking the link on the console removes some special character which produces that kind of error.

Comment: Have you already tried copying the link and pasting it on the browser?